# Should I make my R developments a package?

Tags: r

I am developing a set of R scripts to post-process experimental data.

Currently, these are just scripts that I load individually by manually sourcing them.

I wonder if it would be better to put all those scripts in an R package, but as I constantly add/modify my library functions, I don't really know if this is the recommended way of doing it.

So my question is: should I go on working on "independent" script files or package them?

Comment: I have no more flags left, but imho this is primarily opinion based (and depends on your very situation) and should be closed.

Comment: Yes, package them and use the package infrastructure to document them. Generally, if you decide to split your code into more than one source files, it's usually best to take the small additional step and make a package.

Comment: It's really a question about good practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always good to bundle your scripts into a package. which will help you in lot many ways.

- All your project fundamentals will be packed together
- code portability will be lot easier
- you can have test cases for your function using testthat package
- You can have proper documentation for your code using roxygen2 package, which will help the readers or other users of the code to understand mode about the code.
- you don't have to load your data and functions manually, you just have to load your package by saying library(package_name)

for more details about "R package": http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/